# How can I use SOAP API (XML format) in Python?

Tags: python, soap

I've never used SOAP API before. Unlike REST API, it doesn't seem to be that simple to use SOAP API in Python. As REST API comes with JSON format, you can simply access by doing something like `data.student.name`. I have the below SOAP API coming with XML format.

Can anyone explain how I can access `Rank` in the data in Python code level?

**data (SOAP API)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Awis>
  <OperationRequest>
    <RequestId>6153688e-865c-11e9-84c7-196fdec7da01</RequestId>
  </OperationRequest>
  <Results>
    <Result>
      <Alexa>
        <Request>
          <Arguments>
            <Argument>
              <Name>url</Name>
              <Value>sfgate.com</Value>
            </Argument>
            <Argument>
              <Name>responsegroup</Name>
              <Value>Rank</Value>
            </Argument>
          </Arguments>
        </Request>
        <TrafficData>
          <DataUrl>sfgate.com/</DataUrl>
          <Rank>1441</Rank>
        </TrafficData>
      </Alexa>
    </Result>
    <ResponseStatus>
      <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
    </ResponseStatus>
  </Results>
</Awis>
```

Comment: https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer, but It may help someone with a similar problem.

The response in the question is from **Alexa AWIS API**, which returns a response in XML format which needs to be parsed in some sort of JSON or python dict format to access the values in it.

I also faced this problem and resolved it by parsing using this function, which uses `xmltodict` library for parsing XML to dict and after that recursively fixes dict keys.

```py
def xml_to_json(xml_str):
    
    def fix_dict(a_dict):
        new_dict = a_dict.copy()
        for k,v in a_dict.items():
            
            if k.startswith('aws:'):
                k = k[4:]
                del new_dict["aws:"+k]
            
            if k.startswith("@"):
                del new_dict[k]
                continue
                
            if type(v) == dict:
                v = fix_dict(v)
            elif type(v) == list:
                v = [fix_dict(i) for i in v if type(i)==dict]

            new_dict.update({k:v})

        return new_dict
    
    parsed_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_str, dict_constructor=dict, cdata_key='text')
    fixed_dict = fix_dict(parsed_dict)
    return fixed_dict
```